Issues with Redis Authentication and Connection EOF Errors in Azure AKS/Kubernetes Cluster
I’m experiencing recurring errors in my Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) environment related to Redis authentication and unexpected connection closures. The errors are generated across different components (coredns, echo-server, and agent) and are captured in Datadog logs.
Here are some examples of the errors I’m seeing:
Redis Authentication Error
2024-10-27 07:45:08 UTC | CORE | ERROR | (pkg/collector/worker/check_logger.go:71 in Error) | check:redisdb | Error running check: [{"message": "Authentication required.", "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last): File "/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.11/site-packages/datadog_checks/base/checks/base.py", line 1228, in run self.check(instance) ... redis.exceptions.AuthenticationError: Authentication required. "}]

Remote Connection EOF

client.go:528] "remote connection EOF" connectionID=7018

CoreDNS Warning

[WARNING] No files matching import glob pattern: custom*/.override
I’m unsure if the authentication errors with Redis are related to the AKS/Kubernetes configuration or an issue with Redis itself. Additionally, the EOF errors suggest there may be connection instability.
What I’ve Tried:
• Restarted all pods - they are healthy and running.
• Checking the AKS network configuration for any potential connectivity issues. the obvious one is client.go:528] "remote connection EOF" connectionID=7018
• Reviewing the CoreDNS configuration for potential misconfigurations.
Environment Details:
• Cloud Provider: Azure
• Service: Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)
• Monitoring: Datadog
• Relevant Logs: Collected via Datadog’s Log Explorer
Any insights on how to resolve the Redis authentication issues and prevent the connection EOF errors would be greatly appreciated!

Are you sure there is no restrictive Network Policies? Share your environment details like the yaml files, the kubectl logs and exec status into your redis pods. data dog integration was succesful? Kindly share all the details for better understanding

To address the authentication and connection EOF errors you’re encountering, you can do few troubleshooting steps to see where the issue lies. For example, deploying a Redis client and testing and verifying that the Redis password is correctly configured or not then review or adjust CoreDNS configurations and cross check the network policies. If you still facing issue, then follow the below step -
Deploy Redis (I did using helm)
helm repo add bitnami https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
helm install redis-release bitnami/redis \
  --namespace redis \
  --set auth.password=$REDIS_PASSWORD \
  --set replica.replicaCount=1


check if redis pods are up or not and if you can exec into them
kubectl get pods -n redis


This is I believe the place where you are getting issue. To test Redis connections and authentication, deploy a Redis client.
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: redis-client
  namespace: redis
spec:
  containers:
  - name: redis-client
    image: redis
    env:
    - name: REDIS_PASSWORD
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: redis-password
          key: password
    command: ["sh", "-c", "redis-cli -h redis-release-master -a $REDIS_PASSWORD ping && sleep 3600"]



Check if the client can connect and authenticate with Redis
kubectl logs redis-client -n redis

You should see PONG, indicating a successful Redis connection.

Store Datadog API Key as a Kubernetes Secret
kubectl create secret generic datadog-secret --from-literal=api-key=<YOUR_DATADOG_API_KEY> -n redis


Deploy the Datadog Agent
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: datadog-agent
  namespace: redis
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: datadog-agent
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: datadog-agent
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: datadog-agent
        image: datadog/agent:latest
        env:
        - name: DD_API_KEY
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: datadog-secret
              key: api-key
        - name: DD_SITE
          value: "us5.datadoghq.com"
        - name: DD_HEALTH_PORT
          value: "5555"
        - name: KUBERNETES
          value: "true"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8125
        - containerPort: 8126


The Datadog Agent should now monitor logs and metrics, providing insights into Redis connections and potential issues.

As you can see, the Redis setup is performing well under load, with 10,000 requests completed in just over 1 second, using 50 parallel clients.
References:

Connectivity troubleshooting
Kubernetes-hosted client application

